# View block - show only field content from own page

Tags: 7, views

I am creating a view block to be displayed on every page of a specific content-type. Among other things, this view shows a field from that content type. How can I configure the view so that it will only display the field data **from the page it is on**? Right now it shows the data from **every** instance of that content-type field. Is there a way to reference the 'parent' page only?

Comment: You can use the contextual filters option in the advanced section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You van do this with a contextual filter on your  block view.

There is a very gold tutorial located here: http://dannyenglander.com/blog/using-views-contextual-filters-create-related-content-block-drupal-7

If anything is unclear dont hesitate to ask! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the example! Using a contextual filter on Content:Nid is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **contextual filter** on your block view for **Node Id**. Then Under "**When the filter value is NOT available**", select **Provide default value** and choose in the select list, **Content ID from URL**.